E2C Email Replies for multiple cases
We have users creating multiple e2c Cases by sending a single email addressed to multiple e2c addresses. They will then make replies within those cases as a ReplyAll with the assumption that the reply will then appear in the history of both Cases.
Sometimes this works, but other times it does not. I am attempting to figure out why this happening. What is it that is being used to identify if the newly created ReplyAll message should appear in another Case ? Is it the ClientThreadIdentifier within the message ? Is it the ThreadIdentifier ?

See Lightning Threading Token doc (assuming you have that enabled)

I have done that, and we have that enabled. Thank you very much for this. @cropcredy

Is there a way for me to check to compare two different replies created between two different Cases (which were originally created by the same Email) should have the same Lightning Threading Token within the email ? I am trying to figure out why some of the user's ReplyAll emails are not going to both of the Cases. When I read about the Lightning Threading Token it wasn't clear how I would  get that information from a message. It says it's in either Header, body, or subject. I don't see it in the subject. I imagine it is invisible in the body or header...? @cropredy

The LTT is created after the Case is created and included in the auto-response reply from the Case. Thus, I would expect the customer to have received two email replies, each with a different LTT. I presume you are showing the LTT in the subject or body. There's a fallback to using the email headers when the LTT is not present. Refer to the doc.
